# Find $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{(\log{x})^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{(\log{x})^n}$.

My book says that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{(\log{x})^n}{x} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{y^n}{e^y} = 0$, but I don't see how that is true.

Comment: Your book is just defining $y = \log x$

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{y^n}{e^y}~dy~=~n!$

Answer (score 1):

First, set $y=\log x$ to get 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\log x)^n}{x}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^n}{e^y}$$

Then, assuming that $n$ is a positive integer, use L'Hopital's rule $n$ times to obtain
$$ \lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^n}{e^y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{ny^{n-1}}{e^y}=\cdots =\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{n!}{e^y}=0 $$

Therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{(\log x)^n}=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the L'Hopital's rule, 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^n e^{-x} 
= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x} $$

Then applying L'Hopital's rule, we have: 
$$= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}} { e^x} $$

Applying L'Hopital's rule again we have: 
$$= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n(n-1)x^(n - 2)} { e^x} $$

And again: 
$$= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2)x^{n - 3}}{e^x} $$

Now say we apply L'Hopital's rule n times. Then we get: 
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n! x^{n - n}} {e^x} $$

$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n! x^{0}} {e^x} $$

$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!} {e^x} $$
$$= n!\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1} {e^x} $$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the power series representation of the exponential function, often taken as a definition $$\exp x :=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n \over n!} $$ and note that for positive $x$ and integer $c$ we clearly have

$$\sum_{k=0}^c{x^k \over k!} <\exp x $$

Now take $c>n$

so that $$0<\frac{x^n}{\exp x}<\frac{x^n}{\sum_{k=0}^c{x^k \over k!}}$$

for large enough $x$ and note the RHS $\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ (this can be clearly seen by dividing the numerator and the denominator by $x^n$). The squeeze theorem proves the result.

Formally, this means that $x^n \in o(e^x)$ as $x \to \infty$ and is an important property of $\exp$.